How to add an api key to discovery loaded beta endpoint for the google js client library
I'm trying to get support for the file upload endpoint that is part of the betav1 version.  Which hasn't been added to the generative ai js library yet.
I can load the discovery doc and call the file endpoint

require('dotenv').config();

const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY; // Get the api key from env
const MODEL_NAME = process.env.TEXT_MODEL_NAME_LATEST; // Get the model name from env

// Importing the GoogleGenerativeAI class from the "@google/generative-ai" package
const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");

// Access your API key as an environment variable (see "Set up your API key" above)
const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI(process.env.API_KEY);

async function run() {
    // For text-only input, use the gemini-pro model
    const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: MODEL_NAME},{apiVersion: 'v1beta',});

    const prompt = "Write a story about a magic backpack."

    const result = await model.generateContent(prompt);
    const response = await result.response;
    const text = response.text();
    console.log(text);
}

run();

Its resulting in an error as its not adding the api key.
 errors: [
    {
      message: "Method doesn't allow unregistered callers (callers without established identity). Please use API Key or other form of API consumer identity to call this API.",
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'forbidden'
    }
  ],


Any one know how to add the api key to this?

After a lot of back and forth it seams you can load the key directly into the serivce
const service = google.discoverAPI(discoveryUrl, { auth : apiKey});

full sample
const { google } = require('googleapis');
require('dotenv').config();
const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY; // Get the api key from env
async function createService(apiKey) {
  const discoveryUrl = `https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta&key=${apiKey}`;
  try {
    const service = google.discoverAPI(discoveryUrl, { auth : apiKey});
    return service;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching discovery document:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}

// Usage
createService(API_KEY)
    .then(async service => {
        // You can use the service object here

        const res = await service.files.list({
            pageSize: 100,
        });
        console.log(res)
        const files = res.data.files;
        if (files.length === 0) {
            console.log('No files found.');
            return;
        }

        console.log('Files:');
        files.map((file) => {
            console.log(`${file.name} (${file.id})`);
        });
        //console.log('Service created:', service);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error creating service:', error);
    });

